# git svn clone get stuck after Initialized

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am using tortoisegit to clone svn repository. Which get stuck after git initialization. I can see following command is running in logs:

```
git.exe svn clone "https://<svn url>" "E:\project" -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

When I tried this command in command line, then also same thing happening. So no issue with tortoisegit.

It works on my old laptop. But it doesn't work on my new system. It always give following error and no information after that:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in E:/project/.git/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, and after reinstalling my Git, the problems has been solved.
The only thing I changed when reinstalling was the SHH executable: "Use (Tortoise) PLink" instead of "Use OpenSSH".